# How to generate sources for multiple services using Apache CXF codegen plugin for Maven under one execution

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm currently using the Apache CXF codegen plugin (version 3.1.1) for Maven to generate sources from our client-provided WSDL. I have the wsdl2java goal specified, and I want to generate code for multiple services. I know you can specify a `<serviceName>` under the `<wsdlOption>` tag, but when I try to put more than one `<serviceName>`, or even create another `<wsdlOption>` using the same `<wsdl>` value with a different `<serviceName>`, it seems to ignore one of them and just generate the classes for one service.

The only way around this that I've found is to create another identical `<execution>` block and just change the `<serviceName>`. Am I doing something wrong, or is that the only way to do it? Here is the overall setup for one `<execution>` (the paths and service names have been changed for privacy's sake):

```
<execution>
    <id>generate-sources-a</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <defaultOptions>
            <bindingFiles>
                <bindingFile>binding.xjb</bindingFile>
            </bindingFiles>
        </defaultOptions>
        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlRoot>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
        <includes>
            <include>Path/To/WSDL/MyWSDL.wsdl</include>
        </includes>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/Path/To/WSDL/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
                <serviceName>ServiceA</serviceName>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

I've tried both this:

```
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/Path/To/WSDL/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
        <serviceName>ServiceA</serviceName>
        <serviceName>ServiceB</serviceName>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

...and this (used in Example 4 here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html):

```
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/Path/To/WSDL/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
        <serviceName>ServiceA</serviceName>
    </wsdlOption>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/Path/To/WSDL/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
        <serviceName>ServiceB</serviceName>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

**Note that these services are from the same WSDL provided by our client.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your last solution worked for me with below confi

cxf.version>3.4.0

```
<wsdlOptions>
   <wsdlOption>
     <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdl1.wsdl</wsdl>
   </wsdlOption>
   <wsdlOption>
     <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdl2.wsdl</wsdl>
   </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```